# Report Viewer Conditional Sum

Tags: reportviewer

In Visual Studio Report Viewer I need to sum the values in a column that satisfy a condition present in a second column

For example like this column 3:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2UaW.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have to Set these expressions:

Cell expression:
=IIf(IsDate(Fields!Col2.Value),Fields!Col1.Value,Nothing)

Sum expression:
=Sum(CDbl(IIf(IsDate(Fields!Col2.Value), Fields!Col1.Value,0)))